# Why there is no 3category or tricategory of bicategories?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, higher-category-theory

I have read around about bicategories, lax functor, lax natural transformation and modifications.
I know that we have a 1category of Bicategories and lax functors.
I know why we do not have a bicategory or 2category of bicategories, lax functor, and lax natural transformations, and I know that using ICONS instead of lax natural trasformations solves this problem. (or oplax, it doesn't matter)

What I cannot see is why we do not get a 3categories or tricategories of bicategories, Lax functors, ICONS and modifications?
What fails?
Where can I find a reference about it?

Comment: What reference do you have that bicategories, lax functors, icons, and modifications do not form a tricategory?